# How to convert char[ ] to char *?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm wondering how to convert a char[] array to a char *

For example, in my code I am trying to access a web server using a hostname like "example.com"

Using my code, if I set a char * to "example.com" like below, it works perfectly.

```
char *host = "example.com";
```

But, what I really want to do is be able to read from a client program using a socket, write to a char[] array, and use the data obtained from that as the hostname.

For example,

```
char buffer[4096], hostname[4096]; 

bzero(buffer, 4096);
n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 4095);

strcpy(hostname, buffer);
printf("Here is the hostname: %s\n", &hostname[0]);

int sockwb, wbport, x;
struct sockaddr_in webser_addr;
struct hostent *wbhost;
char webbuf[4096];//sending to webserver

wbport = 80;//port used to access web server

sockwb = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

wbhost = gethostbyname(hostname);
```

when my code gets to the last line, it just sits there, so I'm thinking its a typing problem, since when I do this:

```
char *host = "example.com";

...

wbhost = gethostbyname(host);
```

It works, and is able to get the data from the web and send it properly to my client program.

Any ideas are appreciated.

In the client program I use fgets() to read into a char[] from stdin then use write() to write to the socket for the server program to read. I had tried to use strcat() to add '\0' to the end of the char[] before writing to the socket but that didn't seem to do anything

Full Code: (Please ignore the comments, just trying different things for now)
client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  int sockfd, portnum, n;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct hostent *server;

  char buffer[4096];

  if(argc < 3)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  }

  portnum = atoi(argv[2]);
  sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if(sockfd < 0)
  {
    perror("ERROR opening Socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

  if(sockfd  == NULL)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, server->h_length);

  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);

  if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, on connecting");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Please enter the Host name: ");
  bzero(buffer, 4096);
  fgets(buffer, 4095, stdin);
  //strcat(buffer, "\0");

  n = write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));

  if(n < 0)
  {
    printf("Error writing to socket");
    exit(1);
  }

  bzero(buffer, 4096);
  n = read(sockfd,buffer, 4095);

  if(n < 0)
  {
    printf("ERROR reading from socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("%s\n", buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int sockfd, newsockfd, portnum, clilen;
    char buffer[4096], hostname[4096];
    pid_t p_id;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n, pid, hostname_len;
    //char *host;
    char *host = "example.com";

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, NO PORT PROVIDED!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);//socket is made

    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR opening socket!!");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portnum = atoi(argv[1]);//port num

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portnum);


    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( listen(sockfd, 5) < 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR ON LISTEN");
        exit(1);
    }

    // accept
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    do{

        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &clilen);
        if(newsockfd < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR on accept\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0)
        {
            bzero(buffer, 4096);
            n = read(newsockfd, buffer, 4095);

            if(n < 0)
            {//message from client
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR Reading from socket\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            strcpy(hostname, buffer);
            printf("Here is the hostname: %s\n", &hostname[0]);

            //variables used for acsessing webserver?
            int sockwb, wbport, x;
            struct sockaddr_in webser_addr;
            struct hostent *wbhost;
            char webbuf[4096];//sending to webserver

            wbport = 80;//port used to access web server

            sockwb = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

            if(sockwb < 0)
            {
                printf("Error opeing websocket\n");
                exit(1);
            }


        //    hostname_len = sizeof(hostname) / sizeof(hostname[0]);
        //    printf("%d\n", hostname_len);
        //    memcpy(host, hostname, hostname_len);
        //    host[hostname_len] = '\0';
            printf("%s\n", host);
        //    hostname[hostname_len] = '\0';

        //    host = &hostname[0];

            //wbhost = gethostbyname(hostname);
            wbhost = gethostbyname(host);
            //printf("%s", wbhost->h_name);

            printf("here2\n");

            /*if(wbhost == NULL)
            {
                printf("NO SUCH web HOST\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            */
            bzero((char*) &webser_addr, sizeof(webser_addr));

            webser_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

            bcopy((char *)wbhost->h_addr, (char *)&webser_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, wbhost->h_length);

            webser_addr.sin_port = htons(wbport);

        //    printf("here3\n");

            if(connect(sockwb, (struct sockaddr *) &webser_addr,sizeof(webser_addr)) < 0)
            {
                printf("Error on web connecting\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            bzero(webbuf, 4096);
            strcpy(webbuf, "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ");
        //    strcat(webbuf, hostname);
            strcat(webbuf, host);
            strcat(webbuf, "\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");


        //    const char * request = "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

        //    printf("%s\n", request);
        //    x = write(sockwb, request, strlen(request));

            printf("%s\n", webbuf);
            x = write(sockwb, webbuf, strlen(webbuf));

            if(x < 0)
            {
                printf("Error writing to web sock");
                exit(1);
            }

            bzero(webbuf, 4096);
            x = read(sockwb, webbuf, 4096);

            if(n < 0)
            {
                printf("Error reading from web socket");
                exit(1);
            }

            printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(webbuf));
            printf("%s\n",webbuf);

            n = write(newsockfd, webbuf, 4095 );//write back to client

            if(n < 0)
            {
               fprintf(stderr, "ERROR WRITING to socket");
               exit(1);
            }

            //printf("%s\n", webbuf);
        }//end of if pid==0

        printf("closing client");
        close(newsockfd);//closing client socket


    }while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you include the trailing null byte in your message? Anyway, there's an implicit conversion from `char[N]` to `char*`, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @cad I don't think so? In the client program I use fgets() to read into a char[] from stdin then use write() to write to the socket for the server program to read. I had tried to use strcat() to add '\0' to the end of the char[] before writing to the socket but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Edit that **into your question**, not as a comment.

Comment: From `man fgets`: "A terminating null byte (`'\0'`) is stored after the  last  character  in
       the buffer." So, the `strcat` is superflous.

Comment: `fgets` can append a newline character to the string. You should remove that using `char* ptr = strchr(hostname, '\n'); if (ptr) *ptr = '\0'`.

Comment: @cad ok, I haven't been using the strcat since it didn't seem to do anything, but I still can't figure out why if I use what I send over the socket for the hostname, the server won't work properly.

Comment: @cad so I should do that before I send it over the socket correct?

Comment: Use `printf`s to determine the line your program runs forever at. Do some debugging. As it stands, your question seems to be an XY-problem. Add the full code. Try to imagine being me and what I need to understand your code and problem perfectly.

Comment: Yes, try it. Dunno if it'll work because the problem might be another line but the newline's definitely problematic as well.

Comment: @cad I added the full code I have so far without making any changes you have recommended

Comment: `char *host2 = hostname;` will get you a `char *` ... but based on your description that is actually nothing at all to do with your problem. It seems that you actually want to know why "it just sits there," when you call `gethostbyname`. Your title and introduction should focus on that instead.

Comment: @M.M I have tried to do `char *host = hostname;` and the program still hangs up when I use `wbhost = gethostbyname(host);` at the line: `bcopy((char *)wbhost->h_addr, (char *)&webser_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, wbhost->h_length);`  so I figured since it works when just using a char * then I should try to convert the char[] that I read from the socket to a char pointer

Comment: @Blake `char *host = hostname;` *does* convert the char[] you read from the socket to a char pointer.  So this shows that that is not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @M.M hmm, ok. Then I'm not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: @Blake most likely, the hostname array does not really contain what you think it does.   For example perhaps the string is not null terminated (but even if it is, you should not rely on the other end to be sending the null terminator -- that is just a recipe for a remote exploit). Use your debugger or a hex-dump printf statement to print exactly what is in the `buffer` array after you read from the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted runs unimpeded. When you ask for help, you should always post a [complete, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Check that the code you post actually reproduces the problem!

Looking at what the code does, it seems that in the server, you meant to use the host name that you read as the argument to `gethostbyname`. You can do that with

```
host = &hostname[0];
```

or simpler

```
host = hostname;
```

or by not using two separate variables in the first place.

When you use an array in a context that expects a value (as opposed to e.g. taking its address or its `sizeof`), the array decays into a pointer to its first element. So here `hostname` is equivalent to `hostname[0]`.

After that change, check the trace closely, or, to make the problem more visible, change the tracing line to

```
            printf("[%s]\n", hostname);
```

You'll see

```
[aaa.com
]
```

The client reads a line with `fgets`, which includes the terminating newline character in its count. The client dutifully forwards the complete line to the server. And so the server looks up a host name containing a newline character, which doesn't exist. You don't check the return code of `gethostbyname` (you should!), it returns a null pointer, and the program crashes when it tries to read from it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for helping me see that there is a newline character there, I didn't thin about checking it that way. What would be the best way to remove it? so it would be `[example.com]`

Comment: @Blake Typically: find the end of the string (with `strchr(buffer, 0)` with `strlen`), check whether that's the first byte (empty input), and if it's not check the byte before the null byte, and if that's a newline replace it by a null byte.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot along with @Koffee's help!

Answer (score 1):

@Gilles is right, you have an '\n' at the end of the hostname, the following piece of code replaces the '\n' by 0 which is the equivalent of the character '\0':

```
    extern int h_errno;
    ...
    hostname[strlen(hostname) - 1] = 0;
    wbhost = gethostbyname(hostname);

    if (!wbhost) {
      printf("Failed! %s\n", strerror(h_errno));
      exit(1);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to 'convert' `char[]` to `char *` is:

```
char example_array[] = "example";
char * example_pointer = (char *)calloc(1, strlen(example_array) + 1); // + 1 for the '\0' character
strcpy(example_pointer, example_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `char[]` is an array of chars. A `char*` is a pointer to a char - generally (but not always) the start of a string.

If you want to get a pointer to the start of your array, you don't even need to do anything! This conversion happens implicitly:

```
char hello[6] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
// or: char hello[] = "hello"; (equivalent to above)
printf("%s", hello); // prints hello
puts(hello); // also prints hello

char *hello2 = hello;
puts(hello2); // also prints hello
```